# Android Studio: App keeps crashing on start

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

Something very strange is happening to me. The last time I ran my app through Android Studio it works fine. Then the second time, even when I didn't change anything, it crashes on open. Here is the logcat:

> 05-14 20:13:45.718 25075-25082/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
>   05-14 20:13:46.644 25075-25075/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.breunig.nathan.progressbarderby, PID: 25075
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(118692000bytes) bitmap.
>                                                          at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
>                                                          at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)
>                                                          at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:528)
>                                                          at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1316)
>                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17185)
>                                                          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16167)
>                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
>                                                          at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1230)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
>                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17188)
>                                                          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16167)
>                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
>                                                          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
>                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
>                                                          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
>                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
>                                                          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
>                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
>                                                          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
>                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
>                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17188)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:754)
>                                                          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16167)
>                                                          at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:648)
>                                                          at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
>                                                          at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:762)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2800)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2608)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2215)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6338)
>                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
>                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
>                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
>                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

Makes no sense. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project to no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to clean and rebuild ?

Comment: the error state that Canvas: trying to draw too large(118692000bytes) bitmap.. please reduce your images in your layout

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using a very large bitmap that the canvas could't handle it. Maybe you can change the image resource that you want to shown up.

Answer (score 0):

> Java.lang.RuntimeException: `Canvas`: 
>   trying to draw too large(118692000bytes) `bitmap`

You are trying to draw a very large `Bitmap`(`around 118MB`) on `Canvas`. To resolve this error try to reduce the size of `bitmap` and draw on `canvas`.

**You can also use `Bitmap decoding` method:**

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
String imageType = options.outMimeType;
```

See documentation about [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html#read-bitmap)

Hope this will help~